# HttpComponents freezes when calling HttpResponse response2 = conn.receiveResponseHeader();

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying some basic stuff with `HttpComponents`.

I'm getting a strange issue with `conn.receiveResponseHeader();`. Perhaps I'm not using it properly, but I cannot see what it is.

When the program reaches this line, it simple pauses indefinitely. When I debug, and evaluate that expression it says "(pending)" forever.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, HttpException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("www.booya.com", 80);
        DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
        HttpRequest request2 = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", "/");
        conn.bind(socket);
        conn.sendRequestHeader(request2);
        HttpResponse response2 = conn.receiveResponseHeader();
        System.out.println(response2.getAllHeaders());
        System.out.println(conn.isOpen());
        HttpConnectionMetrics metrics = conn.getMetrics();
        System.out.println(metrics.getRequestCount());
        System.out.println(metrics.getResponseCount());
        System.out.println(metrics.getReceivedBytesCount());
        System.out.println(metrics.getSentBytesCount());
        conn.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to flush internal session buffer

```
 conn.bind(socket);
 conn.sendRequestHeader(request2);
 conn.flush();
```